# simpleDateformat parsing issue

Tags: java

```
Timestamp tsmp = Timestamp.valueOf("0302-02-20 00:00:00");
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.format(tsmp));
```

this code segment prints : **0302-02-20 12:00:00**
why is that? Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 8):

You're using `hh`, which is 12-hour format ("Hour in am/pm (1-12)" as specified in the docs). Use `HH` instead.

```
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

You should pretty much *never* use `hh` unless you're also using `a`, the AM/PM designator.

(Did you really mean to create a timestamp in the year 302AD though, out of interest?)

Answer (score 3):

> new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

Read the API again. The time symbols are not all lower case characters.

Comment: The OP already realized they weren't all lower case, as he was using `MM` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");